# Integrate JDBC driver into a Docker Container (jupyter/all-spark-notebook) running Spark (PySpark)

Tags: docker, apache-spark, jdbc, jupyter

In order to play around with Spark, I am using a public image (jupyter/all-spark-notebook) available [here](https://github.com/whole-tale/all-spark-notebook/blob/master/README.md) which gives you basically:

- **Jupyter Notebook**
- **pyspark**
- **pandas**
- *few others*

The way I create the container is the following:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 4040:4040 -v /${pwd}://root/data jupyter/all-spark-notebook
```

I expose two ports. One for the jupyter notebook and another for monitoring Spark Jobs.
But, what I want to do in addition to that is adding a JDBC connectivity options, so I can make queries to another Docker container which is running [MS SQL Server 2019](https://mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest).

I have downloaded a .jar file (sqljdbc42.jar) which is supposed to play the role of the driver but I am not really sure where I should place in the container itself and in general I am wondering how to run some spark using JDBC to query that MS SQL Server.